# NSURLSessionUploadTask doesn't send file

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I've having a few issues with a NSURLSessionUploadTask. I'm attempting to upload an image I've selected using the UIImagePickerController. I have a PHP page that currently would either send back 'true' if the file exists, and 'false' is it doesn't. I receive false. I've tested the PHP page with Postman, and it works perfectly. Hence, I'm positive the issue lies with iOS.

Here's the file upload:

```
func uploadFile(fileData: NSData) {
        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.codekaufman.com/file.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: .defaultSessionConfiguration())

        let uploadTask = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromData: fileData, completionHandler:{
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
                return
            }

            println(response.description)
            println()

            var err: NSError?
            var receivedData: [String]!
            receivedData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? [String]

            if(receivedData != nil) {
                println(receivedData)
            } else {
                println("No data recieved.")
            }

        })

        uploadTask.resume()
    }
```

Here's the PHP just for kicks:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display errors', 1);

if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo json_encode('true');   
} else {
    echo json_encode('false');   
}

?>
```

Here's the NSURLResponse:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff4f062bd10> { URL: https://www.codekaufman.com/file.php } { status code: 403, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 1551;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 13 Feb 2015 08:05:55 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=200";
    Server = Apache;
} }

No data recieved.
```

Comment: status code of response is 403 (Forbidden),

Comment: @Mateusz I understand that, how can I remedy that though?

Comment: you have to authorize the request

Comment: @Mateusz How would I go about doing that?

Comment: it depends on your server (auth type),